# JRE1.8.0: Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5

Tags: eclipse, java-8

I get the error

> Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5

Upon checking, I could see that the JRE installed on my machine is JRE1.8.0.
Can someone suggest what can be done here to resolve this?

Comment: Check the _compiler compliance level_ in _Project > Properties: Java Compiler_.